# What determines if a svg can be rendered by openlayers

Tags: svg, icons, openlayers

I've got 3 different SVGs that all display a marker. However only one of them works with the Openlayers icon. In this example only svg1 correctly displays the marker on the map. All three SVGs are correctly displayed when using an IMG element. What determines if a svg can be displayed by openlayers or what do i have to change to make it work?

```
    var svg1 = '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 30 30" enable-background="new 0 0 30 30" xml:space="preserve">' +
        '<path fill="#156BB1" d="M22.906,10.438c0,4.367-6.281,14.312-7.906,17.031c-1.719-2.75-7.906-12.665-7.906-17.031S10.634,2.531,15,2.531S22.906,6.071,22.906,10.438z"/>' +
        '<circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="15" cy="10.677" r="3.291"/></svg>';

    var svg2 = '<svg width="30" height="30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" enable-background="new 0 0 30 30" version="1.1"><g><title>Layer 1</title><path id="svg_1" d="m22.906,10.438c0,4.367 -6.281,14.312 -7.906,17.031c-1.719,-2.75 -7.906,-12.665 -7.906,-17.031s3.54,-7.907 7.906,-7.907s7.906,3.54 7.906,7.907z" fill="#156BB1"/></g></svg>';
    var svg3 = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512"><path fill="#156BB1" d="M172.268 501.67C26.97 291.031 0 269.413 0 192 0 85.961 85.961 0 192 0s192 85.961 192 192c0 77.413-26.97 99.031-172.268 309.67-9.535 13.774-29.93 13.773-39.464 0zM192 272c44.183 0 80-35.817 80-80s-35.817-80-80-80-80 35.817-80 80 35.817 80 80 80z"></path></svg>';

    var mysvg = new Image();
    mysvg.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + encodeURIComponent(svg1);

    var style = new Style({
        image: new Icon({
            img: mysvg,
            imgSize: [30, 30]
        })
    });
```

Comment: the difference between svg1 and svg2 seem to be the svg parameters. Changing the order makes it possible to display svg2. That means the order is important, when using SVGs in Openlayers.

svg3 still makes sense to me though. I've tried copying the <path> element to a previous working svg and that makes it stop working.

Comment: svg1 and svg2 are working for me with Chrome.  For svg3 I need `imgSize: [384 * 4, 512 * 4], scale: 0.02` to see something similar to the others, so maybe there is a problem with the viewBox in that?

Comment: OpenLayers renders SVG images by setting them as `src` of an Image element. As such, the browser needs to know the size of the image. For an SVG, this means it needs `width` and `height` parameters on the root `svg` element. This question is actually not about OpenLayers, but about how a browser renders Image elements with SVG as image format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the order and the parameters used are of importance for Openlayers. I've got svg3 working by using the following as svg wrapper.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" width="30px" height="30px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 384 512">
</svg>
```

Removing any of those parameters or changing the order resulted in the svg not showing on the map. Another issue was that the path values were not comma separated. That poses no issue with displaying it in an image but openlayers seems to require it at least for usage within an Icon.

Comment: It will be drawImage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage which is not working https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=700533 so not specific to OpenLayers